# Real time update for voting system with an ajax call

Tags: javascript, ajax, freemarker

Hi I'm trying to create a voting system on my web app that allows users to vote up or vote down on specific images. The functionality seems to work but it does not update in real time, the value is only updated after I refresh the page. Voting up adds one to the score and voting down reduces the score by one. The JQuery I'm using is as follows:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
      $(".vote").click(function(){
       var id = $(this).attr('id').split('_')[1];
       var vote_type = $(this).hasClass('up') ? 'up' : 'down';
          $.ajax({
              url: "/voting/",
              type: 'POST',
              data: {id: id, type: vote_type},
              success: 
          });
          return false;
      });
 });
```

On the server side I just find the post in the model that has a matching id and edit the votes accordingly then pass it to the google datastore. I'm wondering is there any way I can update the view to display the value that is now stored in the model but not yet appearing on screen. Thanks.

Comment: the success attribute of the ajax call seems like a good candidate for this task.  Your server-side could return the new vote counts and the success function could update the web page accordingly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can give `$.ajax` a success callback that updates with something like:

```
$.ajax({... success: function(data) {$('#element').val(data)}})
```

This will update the vote count right after casting the vote. However, if you want the vote to update without any user interaction, you can do some kind of polling or publish/subscribe.

Comment: Thanks got it working, I'd give you rep if I could but it requires me to have 15.

Comment: @CiaranGeorge Did you come back just to upvote? Thanks. I appreciate it.